# How to write a Mockito testcase for Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, mockito, testcase

I have the following method :

```
def subsetConversion(fPath: DataFrame): Tuple2[DataFrame, DataFrame] = {

  /* line 87*/ var convertedPaths = fPath.filter(fPath("Conversion") === 1)
  var nonConvertedPaths = fPath.filter(fPath("Conversion") === 0)

  var dataFrameTuple = (convertedPaths, nonConvertedPaths)

  logger.info("Returning converted and non converted data frames" + dataFrameTuple)

  dataFrameTuple

}
```

I've written the following testcase to test the above method :

```
"subset Conversion Data" should "pass this test and divide the input data frame to a tuple of two data frames" in {
  val dataFrameInput = Mockito.mock(classOf[DataFrame])
  val subsetData = uJTrnsfrm.subsetConversion(dataFrameInput)    
  assert(subsetData.isInstanceOf[Tuple2[DataFrame, DataFrame]])    
}
```

where uJTrnsfrm is an instance of the class in which the subsetConversion method is present. On testing this, i get the following exception :

```
    - should pass this test and divide the input data frame to a tuple of two data frames *** FAILED *** java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at com.accenture.aa.dmah.attribution.userjourney.LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformation.subsetConversion(LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformation.scala:87)
  at com.accenture.aa.dmah.test.attribution.userJourneyTransformation.LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest$$anonfun$6.apply$mcV$sp(LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest.scala:76)
  at com.accenture.aa.dmah.test.attribution.userJourneyTransformation.LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest$$anonfun$6.apply(LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest.scala:74)
  at com.accenture.aa.dmah.test.attribution.userJourneyTransformation.LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest$$anonfun$6.apply(LogisticRegressionUserJourneyTransformationTest.scala:74)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
  at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1647)
```

Any suggestions as to what i can do to run it successfully.

Comment: what's `dataFrameInput`? Could it be null?

Comment: @TzachZohar It's a mock object that I'm using(pls see the edit), and thus by definition, won't be null.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to mock complex objects like DataFrame (or RDD) - you'd have to stub lot's of methods (did you stub `filter` and `apply`?) which would make your tests complex and fragile. Better to use a real DataFrame, I recommend https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base